# Transfer a PDE to wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the following PDE.
$$u_{xx}-u_{tt} + au+be^{ct}=0,  \ \ \ \ a,b,c\in R \ \ \ \  \ \ (1)$$

I took this approach:
I am looking for a change of variables to  transform the equation
to 
$$u_{xx}-du_{tt} + f_1(x,t)=0. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
In fact I want to omit the term "$au$" from the equation and then solve the new equation. It would be appreciated if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that there is no way to transfer Eq. (1) to Eq. (2). In order to solve Eq. (1), first we solve the homogeneous Eq. with respect to (1) i.e.

$$u_{xx}-u_{tt} + au=0$$

which is linear Kelin-Gordon equation associated with quantum mechanics. The solution of the eq. can be found in some handbooks.  The solution for the in-homogeneous part of Eq. (1) is in the form $u=Ae^{ct}$ and $A$ can be calculated by substituting it in Eq. (1).